# Unable to refer the path when invoke the Jar file from R

Tags: java, r, jar, path

I am new one for `R` language and question is related to `R` language.
I created simple `Java` program which is used to check the file is available or not.

```
String sampleCSVFileLocation = "source/SampleCSVFile.csv";
File file = new File(sampleCSVFileLocation);
     if (file.exists())
     {
        System.out.println(sampleCSVFileLocation + " is available");
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println(sampleCSVFileLocation + " is not available");
     }
```

I convert this program as `Test.jar` and stored into this location `C:\Demo`.
and I put the `SampleCSVFile` into the same location.
This is my file structure:

```
C:/Demo/Test.jar  
C:/Demo/source/SampleCSVFile.csv
```

I run this code from command line and am getting the correct output and it goes to **IF** block.

```
C:\Demo>java –jar Test.jar
source/SampleCSVFile.csv is available
```

**My Problem is:**
I run the same jar from R language. I am getting **wrong output**. It goes to **else** block.

```
>system(“java –jar C:/Demo/Test.jar”)
source/SampleCSVFile.csv is not available
```

It unable to refer the **source** folder path.
I don’t want change the java code.
How to resolve this issue.

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set working directory, before exec `jar`.

```
setwd("C:/Demo")
```

More information here -http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/getwd.html